# SQL statement to return all rows that have multiple id's

Tags: sql, mysql

[image: example table]

I am trying to construct a SQL query that returns all the rows (id's) that have tag: 3 AND tag: 4 - in this case it is the single row for `564800`, however I can't seem to figure out how to make this work. The image attached shows what progress I've made (it's a really simple example). I am hoping to be able to generalize this statement so that I can pass it any length of tag_ids and it will filter the list to only the applicable id's.

This is the query so far:

```
SELECT cars.id, array_agg(car_tags.tag_id) AS tag_ids FROM "cars" INNER JOIN "car_tags" ON "car_tags"."car_id" = "cars"."id" GROUP BY cars.id;
```

Comment: Can you add the table structure and some sample data?

Comment: Avoid the use of arrays in a relational model. It violates 1NF.

Comment: Do you mean those rows should have tag 3 and 4 only or should for example a row with tag_ids `{3,4,6}` also be fetched?

Comment: @JonasMetzler that's a good question, and a use case that I wasn't thinking about until now. i believe it should also be inclusive of {3,4,6}

Comment: I agree with flyingfox that you should please provide both sample input data of both tables and the expected result of your query.

Comment: Another question: You taged MySQL as your RDBMS, but I thinnk they don't have a function `ARRAY_AGG`, they use `GROUP_CONCAT` instead. So which RDBMS do you really use?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, we can build on your query and add a good `HAVING` clause and/or a `WHERE` clause if necessary.
If you use `MySQL` as your RDBMS as taged in your question, we will need `GROUP_CONCAT` instead of `ARRAY_AGG`.
Then the important question is what conditions exactly should be applied to your query? As I understand from your question and the comments, you want those rows that have at least both tag_id 3 and tag_id 4, but they are allowed to also have other tag_ids. So a correct query for this use case will be this one for `MySQL`:

```
SELECT 
  c.id, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t.tag_id ORDER BY t.tag_id) AS tag_ids 
FROM 
cars c INNER JOIN car_tags t
ON c.id = t.car_id
GROUP BY c.id
HAVING 
  SUM(t.tag_id = 3) > 0 
  AND SUM(t.tag_id = 4) > 0
ORDER BY c.id;
```

The `HAVING` clause will filter out any rows that don't have tag id 3 or don't have tag id 4.

If your use case or your RDBMS differs, we can do some small changes to make above query work correctly.

If for example only tag_id 3 and tag id 4 should appear in the result, no other tag id's, just add a `WHERE` clause: `...WHERE t.tag_id IN (3,4)...` before the `GROUP BY` clause.

If you decide it's enough if one of the tag_id 3 and tag id 4 occurs, but you still want to filter out rows with other tag id's, then keep above `WHERE` clause, but remove the `HAVING` clause.

If you taged an incorrect RDBMS and use another one, some changes might be required. Let's say, your RDBMS is `Postgres` (I take this because they do provide the `ARRAY_AGG` function you talk about).

Then we will need to use `ARRAY_AGG` rather than `GROUP_CONCAT`. And we also can't use this `SUM...` syntax in the `HAVING` clause. We will use a conditional `COUNT` instead:

```
SELECT 
  c.id, 
  ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT t.tag_id ORDER BY t.tag_id) AS tag_ids 
FROM 
cars c INNER JOIN car_tags t
ON c.id = t.car_id
GROUP BY c.id
HAVING 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN t.tag_id = 3 THEN 1 END) > 0 
  AND COUNT(CASE WHEN t.tag_id = 4 THEN 1 END) > 0
ORDER BY c.id;
```

The changes for the two other use cases need to be done accordingly.
Here two sample fiddles: One for [MySQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/ySDT6pIN) and one for [Postgres](https://dbfiddle.uk/H27ZuAlm) that show all the use cases I talk about.

The sample data in those fiddles is similar to yours, I just added some rows to point out the differences between the three use cases.

Please check which of those use cases is yours and what RDBMS you use. Thus I can shorten the answer to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```sql
SELECT c.id, ARRAY_AGG(ct.tag_id) AS tag_ids
FROM cars c
INNER JOIN car_tags ct ON ct.car_id = c.id
WHERE c.id IN (
    SELECT t1.id
    FROM cars t1
    INNER JOIN car_tags t2 ON t2.car_id = t1.id
    WHERE t2.tag_id IN (3, 4)
    GROUP BY t1.id
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t2.tag_id) = 2
)
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY c.id;
```

The subquery finds all cars having both tags of id 3 and 4.  This subquery is used to restrict the outer query to only cars having these two tags.

Comment: Seems your answer is based on pssql?

Answer (score 0):

How about using `exist`? You may need to dynamically construct the where part though:

```sql
SELECT c.id
FROM cars c
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM car_tags ct WHERE ct.car_id = c.id AND ct.tag_id=3)
  AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM car_tags ct WHERE ct.car_id = c.id AND ct.tag_id=4)
-- more exist if the list is longer
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT ID, COUNT(*) AS CountOfOccurrences
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY ID
HAVING CountOfOccurrences > 1;